# Cp-Cv For a gas following Van Der Waal equation of state

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws, heat

How do you derive the relation

$$C_p-C_v= R\left(1 + \frac{2a}{RTV}\right)$$

for a gas obeying [van der Waals equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation) of state? Any leads?

Comment: How do you know you can obtain an equation of this form by making certain assumptions if you don't know what those assumptions are? Wherever you found this formula should say what assumption they had to make for it to be true.

Comment: It is a question in a competitive exam, hence the doubt.

Comment: Does the test question include any extra context? If so, you should include the text of the actual question.

Comment: No sir this is the only text.

Comment: Problem 2 [here](https://www.csun.edu/~jeloranta/CHEM351/example4.pdf) seems to answer your question after a little algebra and I believe with the assumption that V>>b.

Comment: Also related, p.2 and 3 [here](http://satish0402.weebly.com/uploads/9/4/6/7/9467277/bsc_i_paper_ii_aug25.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You could start with $C_V=(\partial U/\partial T)_V=T(\partial S/\partial T)_V$  and *H* and *p* instead of *U* and *V* for $C_p$ as appropriate. Then generate an expansion for *S* as $dS=(\partial S/\partial V)_T dV+(\partial S/\partial T)_VdT$ and differentiate wrt *T*. You should then get an expression in $C_V$ and $C_p$ plus other terms that you can find using the vdw equation.

Comment: Yes but since the vdw equation is not explicit in V, it does not boil down to the above expression. The above expression can be obtained using a specific assumption which is what I am after.

Comment: You should find that the difference in heat capacity is $T(\partial P/\partial T)_V(\partial V/\partial T)_p$ so calculate the derivatives and keep going. It is messy. However, since _a_ is in the answer given in the question a likely solution is that $b=0$. Making this assumption does simplify the answer a bit although its best usually to apply specific limits at the end of a calculation if possible.